# Unable to get a model in Backbone collection by CID

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I have the following mode/collection/view setup in backbone.

```
var Card = {};  

//card model
Card.Model = Backbone.Model.extend();


//collection
Card.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/api/cards',
    model: Card.Model
});

//column view
Card.MainView = Backbone.View.extend({
        className: 'column',
        append: function(model) {
            var view = Card.View.extend({ 
                model : model,
                attributes: { cid : model.cid } 
            });
            var v = new view();
            this.$el.append(v.el);          
        },
        initialize: function() {
            var self = this;
            _.bindAll(this, "sortable");
            this.collection.fetch({ 
                success: function() { 
                    self.render(); 
                } 
            });
        },
        render: function() {
            var self = this;
            for(var i = 0; i < this.columns.length; i++) {
                var col = this.columns[i];
                var column = Card.ColumnView.extend({
                    data: col,
                    cards: self.collection.where({ position : col.position })
                });
                var col = new column();
                this.$el.append(col.el);
            }               
            this.sortable();
        },
        sortable: function() {
            var self = this;
            $(this.el).find('.card-container').sortable({
                connectWith: '.card-container',
                receive: _.bind(function(event, ui) { 
                    var cid = $(ui.item).attr('cid');
                    var card = self.collection.get(cid);
                    //console.log(self.collection.last());
                    console.log('cid', self.collection.get(cid));
                    console.log('index 1', self.collection.at(1));
                    console.log('last', self.collection.last());
                    console.log('collection', self.collection);
                }, this)

            });
        }
});
```

When I try to get a model from the MainView's collection in the `sortable` function it won't log the model by CID. I get the following output.

```
cid undefined CardMetaCollection.js:97
index 1 d {collection: d, attributes: Object, _escapedAttributes: Object, cid: "c2", changed: Object…} CardMetaCollection.js:98
last d {collection: d, attributes: Object, _escapedAttributes: Object, cid: "c249", changed: Object…} CardMetaCollection.js:99
collection d {length: 249, models: Array[249], _byId: Object, _byCid: Object, url: "/api/cards"…}
```

I have tried logging in the `success` callback for the fetch method but I still get undefined returned... Each model does have its own cid. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you ensured that the `cid` attribute is actually being attached to the DOM element in question? Can you make a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 3):

The `.get()` method accepts either `id` or `cid`.  The `id` can be passed directly to the `get`, but `cid` has to be passed as an *object literal*.  Actually, you can pass the `id` in an object literal too and have your code consistent.

```
var cid = ...;
var card = self.collection.get({ cid: cid });

var id = ...;
var card = self.collection.get({ id: id });

var id = ...;
var card = self.collection.get(id);
```

You can have a look at the `.get()` implementation in backbone.js.

**UPDATE**: The `cid` alone can be passed to the `.get()` method in Backbone 0.9.9 or newer (see the [implementation in the current 1.3.3](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.3.3/backbone.js#L985)).

```
var cid = ...;
var card = self.collection.get(cid);
```

In your case, the problem is likely in the attribute "cid" missing on card elements, as [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/348314/ben) writes.  You declared an `.append()` method adding this attribute to new elements, but you call `new column()` instead of it in the `.render()` method.  It seems, that the `column` view does not add the attribute, because your logging finds it `undefined`.

Note: consider using a valid custom HTML attribute name like "data-cid" instead of just "cid", for example.

Comment: In the current version of Backbone (v1.3.3), this is not true -- cid can indeed be passed directly to the .get() method.

Answer (score 0):

- ensure `cid` that you are passing into `self.collection.get(cid)` is a id for any one of the models because the `collection.get` expects model id as the argument. You might want to log the `cid` value too for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

cid use when you pushed differents model to one collection and rest not respond unique id for all request anly individual or maybe REST dont return ID attr or we want to create fake model without rest and push it to collection

```
 var banned = app.request('rest:banList');
  var whiteIp = app.request("rest:inviteList");
   var whiteGroup = app.request("rest:groupList");
            $.when(banned, whiteIp, whiteGroup).done(function (bannedList,  whiteIpList, whiteGroupList) {
                debugger
                var arr = new Backbone.Collection();
                arr.add(bannedList);
                arr.add(whiteIpList);
                arr.add(whiteGroupList);

            });

define(["app"], function (app) {
    var API = {
        getWho: function (data) {
            var whois = new Backbone.Model();
            whois.url = '/admin/whois';
            whois.cid = 'ban';
            var defer = $.Deferred();

            whois.fetch({
                type: 'GET',
                data: data,
                success: function(data){
                    debugger
                    defer.resolve(data);
                },
                error: function(data){
                    defer.reject(data);
                }
            });
            return defer.promise();
        }
    };

    app.reqres.setHandler("rest:getWho", function (data) {
        return API.getWho(data);
    });
});
```